# Obtener fecha más reciente

Tags: date, update, sql-server-2014

tengo una tabla en sql server con 6 columnas

```
nombre|fecha1|fecha2|fecha3|fecha4|fecha
luis|2020-05-01|2020-04-30|null|2020-05-12|null
```

de que manera puedo comparar fecha1 a fecha4 para elegir la más reciente y hacer un `update` en la columna fecha

cual seria la manera más eficiente de hacerlo, pues necesito realizar el update a una tabla de 2,400,000 registros aprox

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Supongo que tienes una columna para la ID ¿o me equivoco?

Comment: César, si la tabla tiene más campos, solo coloque 6 en la pregunta a modo de ejemplo, el ID sería "contrato"

Answer (score 0):

Tabla:

```
create table Test( 
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar(256),
    fecha1 varchar(256),
    fecha2 varchar(256),
    fecha3 varchar(256),
    fecha4 varchar(256),
    fecha varchar(256)
);
```

Update:

```
UPDATE Test t1 
SET t1.fecha = (SELECT 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.fecha1) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.fecha4) THEN t1.fecha1
                        WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.fecha4) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.fecha1) THEN t1.fecha4
                        WHEN t1.fecha1 IS NULL THEN t1.fecha4
                        WHEN t1.fecha4 IS NULL THEN t1.fecha1
                        ELSE NULL
                    END
                FROM 
                    Test t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
```

El ejemplo lo he creado en Mysql ya que no tengo instalado SQL Server, el único problema que podrías tener a la hora de usarlo en otro motor de base de datos es la función para convertir el tiempo a timestamp `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. 
En caso de algún inconveniente con la función basta con buscar el equivalente de esa función para SQL Server.

En resumen actualizo la tabla con una sub-consulta que traerá el valor correspondiente mediante una comparación `case`, además esta comparación está realizada luego de una conversión a `timestamp` para evitar posibles errores.

Cuando solo hay un valor utilizará este para actualizar el nuevo campo, si quieres que quede en `null` cuando sucede esto basta con eliminar las ultimas dos sentencias `WHEN`.

Comment: Gracias, con el ejemplo que me das, solo compara f1 vs f4, pero me oriento mucho, gracias